# google maps callback error on function name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, uncaught-exception

I'm getting this error in webdev console when I run my html page code

```
nc {message: "initialize is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: 
"Error↵    at new nc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…
##################&callback=initialize:137:68"}
```

I've based my code off the googlemaps api sample and only altered styling having not changed the function.

The function was called **initMap** though I have recently changed this to see if it made any difference.

My javascript url is https://comfortestateplanning.co.uk/js/home.js initialize function
and my testing site url is https://comfortestateplanning.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out where the error was and how to answer my own question :)

I've determined that the javascript file with the Google Maps function in it should **not** be *async*. This would cause the function to load concurrently with the Google Maps API call and not after it.

So in my case

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
```

became (without *async*)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
```